# Getting the Left and Right arrow keys to select the previous/next menu instead of the next/previous menu

Tags: winforms, menustrip

Noticed in a full application, but fully reproducable in a simple demo:

I've got a `MenuStrip` containing three menus, `A`, `B`, and `C`. Each of these  menus contains three items, `A1`/`A2`/.../`C2`/`C3`.

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, the first menu `A` becomes selected. I can then use the <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys to select other menus. That is as it should be.

However, when I press <kbd>↓</kbd> to open a menu, I can still use <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> to select other menus, but the order is reversed: <kbd>←</kbd> selects the next menu, and <kbd>→</kbd> the previous.

I'm having trouble figuring out if something is wrong with my local system, if this is a bug in the `MenuStrip` component, or if I am forgetting to set a required property. All three seem strange to me, because in all three cases I would expect *someone* to have encountered this problem already, and I cannot even find anyone else asking about this.

If it's not clear what I'm asking, here is an image:

[image: Menu strip problem]

And before I forget to mention, there is *no* relevant code. This demo application is a brand new WinForms project, has one `MenuStrip` control added to its default form, and has got three menus with three items each, for each of which I have set nothing more than the text.

Comment: Not reproducible by me.  B1 -> goes to C1 on my form.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I guess that probably rules out option three, so that leaves a combination of local system configuration / bug in `MenuStrip`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug/misfeature in `MenuStrip`.

Looking at the `ToolStripDropDown.ProcessArrowKey` implementation with Reflector shows that the arrow keys get reversed depending on `SystemInformation.RightAlignedMenus`. That's not right. It *should* depend on the right-to-left mode of the menu strip itself, which may sometimes (usually?) match `SystemInformation.RightAlignedMenus`, but not always, and not on my system.

`SystemInformation.RightAlignedMenus` is user-configurable via Control Panel, Tablet PC Settings, Other, Handedness, and indeed if I change that to Left-handed, I get the menus to behave correctly. The default and correct setting for me is Right-handed. Since the `MenuStrip` component is simply not keyboard-usable on my system, I will replace my use of it with a standard `MainMenu` component.

*Update*: I'm actually using a derived control to be able to provide nice menu images. It is based on [the Microsoft sample on "Visual Style Menus"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb757020.aspx). A more fully-featured implementation that also works on Windows XP and prior (in that case using owner-drawn menus) is available at [Vista Menu with Icons in C#](http://wyday.com/blog/2008/vista-menu-with-icons-in-c-sharp/), but that is more complicated than necessary for me.

Comment: Thank you for this. I just spent the last few hours puzzling over this problem. I can't believe that more than a year later, this bug still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: The current way I found to change this system setting (as of windows 10) is to Win+R `explorer shell:::{80F3F1D5-FECA-45F3-BC32-752C152E456E}` -> 'Other' tab