# Inverse / Opposite navigation in c# menustrip with direction keys

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, menustrip

I am bulding a C# Windows Forms Application which has a Menu Strip with each menu having a few menu items (just like in notepad).

**The Problem:**
When a menu is **selected**, I can navigate properly with the direction keys(left/right) on the keyboard but when a menu is **Dropdown Opened**, the direction keys(left/right) on the keyboard navigate to the menu in the opposite direction. Left direction key takes me to the right menu and right direction key takes me to the left menu.

Please help me. I've searched a lot on the internet but no luck yet!

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306598/717372

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when you are using "combo box" instead of "Menu item". When you use "Menu item" control the direction keys seems to work the way you want them to.

Comment: I'm not using combo box.

Comment: @SaifShaikh what are you using? If I use MenuItems the navigation works as you wanted?

Comment: I'm using menu items. I told you just like in notepad.

Comment: It will be fixed if I create a new menu strip but I can't afford to write the code for each menu item all over again.

Comment: @SaifShaikh I cannot reproduce this. Without seeing your code I won't be able to assist. Are you creating the menuitems during design time?

Comment: Yes, they're created during design time, not during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

For others to not loose their time searching, the right answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16306598/717372